# How can I convert xml code dynamically to table with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, html-table

I want to display xml code as a table for better readability.
I don't want to use XML parser, just a quick copy, paste converter.
But the way I'm coding it right now, is still very time consuming.
Is there a way to convert it dynamically?
So for every tag in the xml code a new row/cell etc?

In this example the XML is already in the text area. It contains 2 employees. (This will be a lot more, that's why I said time consuming)
With a button you first convert it to innerHTML of a div called "output". I thought that was neccesairy to get the data into the document and convert it to a table. But as you can see, that would mean I would have to adjust the JS code + table for all employees. And some times the xml will contain random number employees. So a dynamical way would be better.
Thank you in advance

```js
function convertxml() {
  var getxml = document.getElementById("inputxml").value;
  document.getElementById("outputxml").innerHTML = getxml;

  name = document.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;

  adress = document.getElementsByTagName("adress")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("adress").innerHTML = adress;

  birthday = document.getElementsByTagName("birthday")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("birthday").innerHTML = birthday;

}
```

```css
input,
button {
  display: block;
}

#outputxml {
  display: none;
}

textarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputxml">
  <employee>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <birthday>01-01-1990</birthday>
    <adress>Streetname 123</adress>
  </employee>
  
    <employee>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <birthday>02-02-2000</birthday>
    <adress>Streetname 123</adress>
  </employee>
  
</textarea>
<button id="convertxml" type="button" onClick="convertxml()">Convert</button>

<div id="outputxml"></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Name:</td>
    <td id="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Adress:</td>
    <td id="adress"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Birthday:</td>
    <td id="birthday"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Use XSL to format it then

Comment: Your question is unclear: On click, do you want one table with ALL the employees in the xml, or just one of them, as in your code snippet? Also, what do you mean by "I don't want to use XML parser" - you ARE dealing with xml, no?

Comment: @JackFleeting thank you for your feedback. With one click, i would want to display ALL employees. In my example I wanted to show what the xml code will look like with multiple employees. Reason not using a DOM Parser is safety. I thought it would be more unsafe than just copy past convert personal details? But would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't place the xml in a `<textarea>` unless it's absolutely necessary, but, more generally, I would create a dynamic table, using xpath, this way:

```js
function convertxml() {
  dest = document.querySelector('#theTable');
  let area = document.evaluate(
    '//textarea',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  const data = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    area.snapshotItem(0).textContent,
    'text/xml'
  );

  results = data.evaluate(
    '//employee',
    data,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < results.snapshotLength; i++) {
    let node = results.snapshotItem(i);

    let info = data.evaluate(
      './/*',
      node,
      null,
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
      null
    );

    let row = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < info.snapshotLength; i++) {
      let item = info.snapshotItem(i);

      row.push(item.textContent);
    }
    dest.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'beforeend',
      `<tr><td>${row[0]}</td><td>${row[1]}</td></td><td>${row[2]}</td></tr>`
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

<textarea id="inputxml">
  <doc>
  <employee>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <birthday>01-01-1990</birthday>
    <adress>Streetname 123</adress>
  </employee>  
    <employee>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <birthday>02-02-2000</birthday>
    <adress>Streetname 124</adress>
  </employee>
  </doc>
</textarea>


<button id="convertxml" type="button" onClick="convertxml()">Convert</button>


<table id='theTable' border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Birthday</td><td>Address</td></tr></table>

  </body>
</html>
```